# logstash Issues with replace logfile time with @timestamp in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, kibana-7

We have a logstash parsing script to parse the logfiles and we have written parsing script for the same. We are facing issue when trying to replace @timestamp with logfile time. Below is the filter that we have used

```
 filter {


json {
    source => "message"
    target => "doc"
 }

mutate {
copy => { "[doc][message]" => "mesg" }
copy => { "[doc][log][file][path]" => "logpath" }
remove_field => [ "[doc]" ]
 }

if (  "/prodlogsfs/" not in [logpath] ) {
drop { }
}
if [logpath] {
dissect {
  mapping => {
    "logpath" => "%{deployment}deployment-%{?id}-%{?extra}"
  }
 }

}

 grok {  match => { "mesg" => [ "^\s?\[%{DATA:loglevel}\] %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logts} \[%{DATA:threadname}\] %{DATA:podname} %{DATA:filler1} \[%{DATA:classname}\] %{GREEDYDATA:fullmesg}",
                                             "(\s)+(?<exception>%{DATA}Exception)[:\s]+(?<trace>(%{DATA}at)+)"
                                        ]
          } }

#Date Filter being used to replace @timestamp with logfile time 
     if [logts] {
 date {
match => [ "logts", "ISO8601" ]
timezone => "Asia/Kolkata"
target => ["@timestamp"] 
}
}
```

With the above code, when we check the value for @timestamp and logts in kibana,  @timestamp shows the currenttime.  Whereas the logts time seems to be a future time (+5.30) . Need help on how to match the @timestamp with logts.

Anyhelp on this is much appreciated.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: +5h30 seems like the time offset of your selected timezone. Maybe the time in the logs is already in the timezone and the configuration option just adds the 5h30?

Comment: Hi Baudap -  thanks for your response.  Yep right, the logfile time is already in IST and the timezone seems to add +5h30.  My criteria here is i want to map the logfile time to @timestamp.  I even changed the timezone to UTC and tested.  But still, it did not work

Comment: I tried to include a ruby code to set the logts time to UTC   ruby {
    
   code => "event.set('logts' , Time.now.utc)"}  But this code actually converts the now time to UTC. Eg,  if the logts time is  on 01-jul-2021, it replaces the time to now -5h30m.  my requirement is I wanted that logts time to be (logts -5h30m) .

Comment: I think the time zone can be changed on kibana itself,
``stack management`` - ``advance settings`` - scroll to ``date format``

Comment: I dont want to change it at kibana level. I wanted to map the incoming logfile time with @timestamp